# CSS Background Animation only in block

Tags: css, css-animations

I have The following animated background, currently displayed on the entire screen, I need you to only visualize in a block (`<div class="c"> </ div>`)

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.bg {
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #6c3 50%, #09f 50%);
  bottom:0;
  left:-50%;
  opacity:.5;
  position:fixed;
  right:-50%;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration:4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration:5s;
}

   

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(25%);
  }
}

.c {margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
        <div class="c">
            <div class="bg"></div>
            <div class="bg bg2"></div>
            <div class="bg bg3"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <h1>Only here animation</h1>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /end animation -->
        <div class="footer">Here without animation</div>
```

I always see on the whole screen, some suggestion to be able to see the animation only in a block (div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add the following css:**

```
.c {  height: 80px; }
.bg { height: 80px; }
```

**Note**: Change the sizes according to your taste.(height)

**example:**

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.c {
    height: 80px;
}

.bg {
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #6c3 50%, #09f 50%);
  bottom:0;
  left:-50%;
  opacity:.5;
  position:fixed;
  right:-50%;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
  height: 80px;
}


.bg2 {
  animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration:4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration:5s;
}

   

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(25%);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="c">
            <div class="bg"></div>
            <div class="bg bg2"></div>
            <div class="bg bg3"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <h1>Only here animation</h1>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /end animation -->
        <div class="footer">Here without animation</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change '.bg' position to relative. Add a "container" div as the parent. The "container" should have the relative position. The footer is going to have the "absolute" position.
Take a look

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer{
position:relative;
bottom:0;
height:50px;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
width: 100%;
}
.bg {
  animation:slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #6c3 50%, #09f 50%);
  bottom:0;
  left:-50%;
  opacity:.5;
  position:absolute;
  right:-50%;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction:alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration:4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration:5s;
}

   

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform:translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateX(25%);
  }
}

.c {margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="c">
            <div class="bg"></div>
            <div class="bg bg2"></div>
            <div class="bg bg3"></div>
            <div class="content">
              <h1>Only here animation</h1>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /end animation -->
        <div class="footer">Here without animation</div>
</div>
```